# Deixar item do listview preenchendo a tela toda

Tags: android, listview

Tem como deixar um item de um ListView tomando a tela toda do celular?

Comment: Por "tela toda" você quer que suma a Action bar e Botton bar?

Comment: não , quero e tipo um fill_parent

Comment: Uma pergunta: para que um `ListView` para isso?

Comment: To querendo ter uma base para uma coisa que to pensando, mais se não tiver como não tem problema

Answer (score 0):

Deixe o **layout_width** e **layout_height** setados com **math_parent**.

No xml da activity apague as seguintes linhas do código:

```js
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
```

**OU** substitua o 16dp de cada linha por 0dp, assim:

```js
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
```

Em styles.xml (app>res>values>**styles.xml**) você modifica a linha `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` por `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`.